# vb lags due too large amount of labels

Tags: vb.net

i created a program that reads a text file then converts each char on the text to become a label. it seems when the text file is too much the program lags or does not show the label or loads too long. is there a way to make it faster or avoid the lag.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Drawing()

    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text)
    RichTextBox1.Text = fileReader
    'MsgBox(fileReader)

End Sub

Private Sub Drawing()
    Dim i, x, y As Integer
    y = 0
    x = 0
    For i = 0 To RichTextBox1.TextLength - 1
        If RichTextBox1.Text.Chars(i) = Convert.ToChar(&HA) Then
            y = y + 16
            x = 0
        Else
            Dim lbl As New Label
            lbl.Name = "lbl"
            lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(15, 15) 'set your size (if required)
            lbl.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Chars(i) 'set the text for your label

            lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y) 'set your location
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(lbl, lbl.Text)
            lbl.BackColor = Color.Red
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection
            x = x + 16
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Panel1.Width = Panel1.Width + 10
    Panel1.Height = Panel1.Height + 10
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Panel1.Width = Panel1.Width - 10
    Panel1.Height = Panel1.Height - 10
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog Then
        TextBox1.Text = dialog.FileName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Drawing()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but you may want to suspend the layout until the process is done. This will complete the drawing without updating the UI or the Form while it is adding up all those labels. Once the labels are loaded, it can draw the whole thing in a single pass.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Drawing()
    Me.ResumeLayout(True)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to make multiple labels. it seems to work on producing at least 1000 labels but i need to produce 5000-1000 labels which gives me an error.